# Requesting music library permissions swift or obj-c

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, mpmediaitem

I want to request music library permissions right when my application opens the first time.

The privacy in my info.plist are:

> Privacy - Media library usage description

and

> Privacy - music usage description

I would prefer this to be in my app delegate did finish launching with options but it is okay if it is in my viewDidLoad of the first viewController of my app.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @Kamran how do I request authorization right when the app starts?

Comment: Asking permissions is always better when user touches the feature that needs it. If your first `ViewController` needs data from library then its fine to ask in `AppDelegate` but otherwise ask in your `ViewController` where it is needed.

Answer (score 6):

You can request for permission like

```
let status = MPMediaLibrary.authorizationStatus()
switch status {
case .authorized:
    // Get Media
case .notDetermined:
    MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization() { status in
        if status == .authorized {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // // Get Media
            }
        }
    }
}
```